# Select Mysql com uma array em uma tabela

Tags: php, mysql, array

Tenho uma tabela no banco chamada atuação, no que gerado os ID`s das áreas escolhidas pelo usuário ex: 1,5,4,9,15

Preciso que o resultado da consulta em Mysql me retorne todos os usuários que tenha sido selecionado em uma lista de checkbox

alguém pode me dar uma luz de como realizar esta pesquisa, ate mesmo sem repetir o usuário caso ele se encaixe em mais de uma área de atuação escolhida?

Vou simplificar com a Consulta IN, que o resultado foi o mesmo

Utilizando

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE atuacao_usuario IN (1,5,6)
```

Me mostra os resultados pos pussuo usuarios na tabela ja com estas areas selecionadas como na imagem
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora se retiro o numeral 1da consulta  `SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE atuacao_usuario IN (5,6)` nao me retorna nenhum resultado

Comment: Insira parte do código que você ja fez no php.

Comment: Boa tarde @AndreiCoelho, ainda não tenho muita coisa de concreto, so criei uma consulta comum, 

Vou colocar a parte do codigo de select na minha pergunta acima

Comment: Opa... melhor agora dá para responder

Comment: WHERE atuacao_usuario IN (1,5,8,7);    https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php

Comment: Tem um edit que eu coloquei na resposta. Tente ele depois.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `OR` dentro do `SELECT`. Assim:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE atuacao_usuario = 1 OR atuacao_usuario = 2 ...
```

Para fazer isso automaticamente. Seu código ficará assim:

```
$array_atuacao = array(1,5,8,7);

$sql_func = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE ";

foreach($array_atuacao as $atuacao){

    $sql_func .= "atuacao_usuario = ".$atuacao." OR ";

}

$sql_func .= substr($sql_func, 0, -3);


$result_func = $mysqli->query($sql_func);   

    while($func = $result_func->fetch_assoc()) {               

        echo $func['nome_usuario'] .' - '.$func['atuacao_usuario'];        
    };
```

Ou, como citado pelo @LeoCaracciolo, você pode usar o `IN`

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE atuacao_usuario IN (1,2,3,4)
```

**EDIT**

Tente fazer assim:

```
$array_atuacao = array(1,5,8,7);

$sql_func = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE ";

foreach($array_atuacao as $atuacao){

    $sql_func .= "FIND_IN_SET('$atuacao', atuacao_usuario ) OR ";

}

$sql_func .= substr($sql_func, 0, -3);
```

Comment: Você pode usar a cláusula IN para substituir muitas condições OR

Comment: Valew @AndreiCoelho, deu certo aqui, so alterei oma concatenação que veio ai na consulta, mas funcionou certinho aqui, obrigado!!

Comment: @MarcosPaulo não esquece de aprovar! Abraço!

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo sim. Vou colocar essa opção.

Comment: Colocando em produção, não deu certo, so funciona se a o primeiro id ( ID da atuacao ) vier marcado.

Onde posso colocar um exemplo funcional?
Ai vc tera uma ideia melhor

Comment: "so funciona se a o primeiro id ( ID da atuacao ) vier marcado" como assim?

Comment: Melhor você inserir tudo na pergunta... HTML, PHP, etc..

Comment: Ok, acabei de editar a pergunta

Comment: @AndreiCoelho, coloquei um exemplo online 
http://consultoriatelejet.com.br/teste.php?id=5,1

Muda os id`s de acordo com a busca

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76761/discussion-between-andrei-coelho-and-marcos-paulo).